# Problema de Conxão com o Intel XDK

Tags: intel-xdk

Sempre que tento logar ou utilizar o Intel XDK as seguintes mensagens aparecem

> A página da web em https://software.intel.com/registration/xdk/?returnID=200 pode estar temporariamente indisponível ou pode ter sido movida permanentemente para um novo endereço da web.

Ou quando vou buildar a aplicação

> **Internet and login are required.** Please verify that you are connected to the internet and logged in a valid Intel XDK user.

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor? Já tentei liberar no firewall, não uso antivírus e a versão do XDK é a 3900, a mais recente.

Comment: See [this XDK forum post for a workaround](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/720758#comment-1900352). We are working on a permanent resolution to the problem, until then, you'll have to use the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, segui as orientações deste link e consegui resolver este problema: (https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/721022)
A primeira vez não consegui, mas estava usando o firefox. Fiz novamente no Chrome e aparentemente resolveu. Pelo que entendi, basicamente você vai se logar no site, depois copiar o cookie gerado numa pasta do programa, atualizando as informações de login.

Comment: Encontrei por acaso este vídeo hoje, demonstrando o processo. Talvez ajude! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=angS4sH2k_w